# Вставка видео в html5

Tags: html5, видео

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтоб вставка с видео в html5 отображалась во всех браузерах. Какие расширения нужно использовать (.ogg, mp4 и т.д.) и что именно нужно указывать в атрибуте TYPE тега SOURCE.

Вот мой пример:

```
<VIDEO CONTROLS POSTER="IMAGES/poster.png">    
<SOURCE SRC="VIDEO/video.mp4" TYPE="video/mp4">    
<SOURCE SRC="VIDEO/video.ogg" TYPE="video/ogg">    
</VIDEO>
```

В моём случае видео отображается только в Safari, Chrome.

Comment: Прочитайте о кодеках тут: [`Тег <video>`][1].


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/html/video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле поддержка видео, да и вообще почти все фичи HTML5 еще очень скудно поддерживается в многих современных браузерах. Пример - IE. Там все очень скудно. Разработчикам остается лишь только ждать и потихоньку дерзать...

Answer (score 0):

При сочетании HTML5 и Flash вы сможете смотреть это видео практически на любом устройстве и браузере.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Видео</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <video id="movie" width="400" height="320" preload controls>
       <source src="video/snowman.mp4" />
       <source src="video/snowman.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
       <source src="video/snowman.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
       <object id="flowplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
          width="400" height="320">
        <param name="movie" value="video/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"video/snowman.mp4"}' />
        <p>Загрузить видео в <a href="video/snowman.mp4">MP4</a>, 
             <a href="video/snowman.ogv">OGG</a> или 
             <a href="video/snowman.webm">WebM</a></p>
       </object>
      </video>
      <script>
       var v = document.getElementById("movie");
       v.onclick = function() {
        if (v.paused) {
         v.play();
        } else {
         v.pause();
        }
       };
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

type указывать не надо.

P.S. зайдите  сюда: [Тег `<video>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/video).